# Unable to use $wpdb in Wordpress

Tags: wpdb

I use mySQL database in Wordpress. 
I'm trying to use simple database query in wordpress.

```
<?php
global $wpdb;
$problems = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM $wpdb->ma_usermeta"); ?>
```

When I run it, I receive POST 500 (Internal Server Error). Without that row ewerything works smoothly.

Same thing happens when I try to get user id:

```
<?php
$user = get_current_user_id(); ?>
```

Can you tell me how to fix it?

Comment: What is this ma_usermeta? You can access the user meta table by $wpdb->usermeta

Comment: ma_usermeta is just a name for my database table. Also when I access the user meta table by $wpdb->usermeta I receive the same error.

Comment: You should see the origin of the error in the error log. This will help you https://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress . Is really hard to guess what is the problem

Comment: Here is the error log:
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function get_results() on null in /wp-content/themes/saveInfo.php:5

Comment: How do you run this file?

Comment: Can you test require_once('../../../wp-config.php'); //this may be different depending on where you try to access the $wpdb within the file system 
global $wpdb;

Comment: i use ajax:
jQuery.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "/wp-content/themes/saveInfo.php",
});

Comment: its not the right way to use ajax on wordpress... but if you still want to use it like this in order to run wordpress functions in custom files you need to include the wp-blog-header.php file that locate in your wp root folder before.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the default way the WP recommend to handle ajax calls. This will save you from lots of pitfalls and bad practices.

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_****', 'your_custom_function' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_****', 'your_custom_function' );

function your_custom_function() {

}
```

**JS part**

```
jQuery.ajax({
    type: "post",
    dataType: "json",
    url: ajax_url,// need the admin_url('admin-ajax.php')
    data: formData, // your data
    success: function(msg){

    }
});
```

[Additional context](https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins)